# I recently installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I was expecting to have the folder MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was expecting to have available:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

but it is not there. I am new to SQL and was wondering if there was a way to install this or do I need to reinstall the whole program? I downloaded 2008 R2 because that is what everyone that I work with uses.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us why do you need to access that folder? In general, you shouldn't mess with the internals of SQL Server. Things should be done through SQL Server Management Studio if possible. The folder you mentioned is for a default installation of SQL Server. If you changed the instance name during installation, it will be named differently.

Comment: There are a lot of data stored in the DATA folder from the link I posted above that is used for other users so I am trying to get it on my SQL. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express was the version I installed. Other people who have installed SQL already have this folder but the only two folders I have in the "Microsoft SQL Server" folder in my program files are called "90" and "100"

Comment: Getting the data files to the other users and have them recreate the databases on their machines is a pain in the butt. You can backup the database and send them the BAK files instead. But I'm still not clear what you want to do.

Comment: the actual data that I need to use would come later. I am just not sure why the MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS is not in my program files at all. I just uninstalled and reinstalled and the same thing happens.

Comment: I figured out that I needed to install a different version that actually contained the folder. as you can see I am extremely new to this. Thanks